# iOS - Swift 4 . - Updated UIButton label title not being used in function

Tags: ios, swift, function, uibutton, label

I have the following code for a button label title (btnTD) which toggles its label title between "L" and "R" ***AFTER*** which it is meant to use the ***UPDATED*** Label title in a function called by another button's action (btnCalculate in this case).

Both the toggling of the label and the function called by btnCalculate work fine.

However, when I toggle the button, the function is using the button's  title label ***BEFORE*** it is changed, not ***AFTER*** it is changed, even though the UI is showing the title toggling correctly.

It doesn't matter what order I put the toggling of the label or the function called by btnCalculate, the result is always the same.

```
    @IBAction func btnTD(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if btnTD.titleLabel!.text! == "R" {
        btnTD.setTitle("L", for: .normal)
    } else {
        btnTD.setTitle("R", for: .normal)
    }

    btnCalculate.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

Here is the code for `btnCalculate.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)` although I don't think it is relevant

```
    @IBAction func btnCalculate(_ sender: UIButton) {
    txtOutput.text = Hold(IBTrk: Int(txtIBT.text!)!, TD: (btnTD.titleLabel!.text!) , OBTime: Double(txtOBTime.text!)!, TAS: Double(Int(txtTAS.text!)!), WD: Int(txtWD.text!)!, WS: Double(txtWS.text!)!)
}
```

Comment: The problem could be that setting the title does so for the `.normal` state, but of course the button is being actively pressed at this time so for a moment it is not in `.normal` state (while calculate method being called). Better to use a variable (e.g. `var state: String = "L"`) and use this in the calculation method, and set the button title to it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `btnTD.currentTitle`  Not **tiltleLabel.Text**

```
   @IBAction func btnCalculate(_ sender: UIButton) {
    txtOutput.text = Hold(IBTrk: Int(txtIBT.text!)!, TD: (btnTD.currentTitle) , OBTime: Double(txtOBTime.text!)!, TAS: Double(Int(txtTAS.text!)!), WD: Int(txtWD.text!)!, WS: Double(txtWS.text!)!)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even know of the current title property !!  It worked great. !!

Comment: This is new to me as well - much simpler than my answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the button title does so for the `.normal` state. However the button is being pressed at this time so for a moment (while calculate function is called) its title is still the old value.

Using a global variable in the view controller is one way around this:

```
// Declare outside a method (in viewController)
var buttonState: String = "L" // Could also be a Bool variable

// Button action
@IBAction func btnTD(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if buttonState == "L" {
        buttonState = "R"
        btnTD.setTitle("R", for: .normal)
    } else {
        buttonState = "L"
        btnTD.setTitle("L", for: .normal)
    }
    // Then call the calculate method
    btnCalculate.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

Note: `btnCalculate.sendActions()` might be better as a separate function that is called here and also from btnCalculate button, rather than using sendActions.

Comment: Chris, your suggestion did work, however Abdelahad Darwish's answer above solved the problem with the least changes.  Thanks for your suggestion

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the feedback.